# text color not changing in html

Tags: html, css

In the below code **text of the color was black but it showing white** .It was showing like this

Home|Service

These color of the text showing white but I gave black. Where did I make the mistake?

```css
#locations {
  width: 1050px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
#locations h1 {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#locations1 table {
  width: 1050px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
}
.hospitails {
  background-color: #A52A2A;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.hospitails_loc ul {
  width: 1050px;
  margin: 1px auto 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
  float: relative;
  color: black;
}
.hospitails_loc ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  color: black;
}
.hospitails_loc li:before {
  content: " | ";
}
.hospitails_loc li:first-child:before {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="locations">
  <h1>Locations</h1>
  <locations1>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tr class="hospitails">
        <td>Hospitails</td>
        <td>Clinics</td>
        <td>Home Care</td>
        <td>Information Centers</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="hospitails_loc">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Service</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <locations1>
</div>
```

Comment: probably some styles that override this ones are setting the color to white, try `color: black!important;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, links will appear as this in all browsers:

An unvisited link is underlined and blue
A visited link is underlined and purple
An active link is underlined and red
You can change the defaults, using styles:

Add this CSS:

```
.hospitails_loc ul li a{color:black;}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vaapurad/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Because the `#locations1 table` selector says it's white?

Comment: Try inspecting that element with Firebug or similar and you should see which CSS rule specifies the white color.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I don't understand the question but I see a problem and a solution. Your are using some kind of custom tag `<locations1>` that should be more like like `<div id="locations1">`.

Your code: http://jsfiddle.net/8e3tcut9/

Modified: http://jsfiddle.net/8e3tcut9/1/